# C++ Embedding Mathematical formulas

Tags: c++, math, documentation

I’d like to know the best practices for documenting Mathematical formulas in C++ code.

Ideally it could have been perfect to be able to write equations directly into comment but it’s not feasible to write them in a Human readable fashion.

I looked to LaTex, MathML and the syntax is complicated when working with many people coming from different horizons (not everyone is mathematician after all). If you have any experience on this area please comment.

For instance, I’m adding cross reference to external HML files in each function that needs to be documented, but it’s hard to maintain. I gave a try to Doxygen formulas and most of us found the syntax very complicated also.

```
  \f[
    |I_2|=\left| \int_{0}^T \psi(t) 
             \left\{ 
                u(a,t)-
                \int_{\gamma(t)}^a 
                \frac{d\theta}{k(\theta,t)}
                \int_{a}^\theta c(\xi)u_t(\xi,t)\,d\xi
             \right\} dt
          \right|
  \f]
```

Comment: The Doxygen formulas are just LaTeX math mode. There are quite a few LaTeX equation editors you could use to generate the LaTeX you put in Doxygen's comments though.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but traditionally one doesn't italicize the "d" in e.g. "dξ".  So, in LaTeX, you would write something like `\mathrm{d}\xi`.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use "ASCII" art.  If your editors support Unicode (particularly, UTF-8 encoded), all the better.  It might be more readable when actually looking at the code.  Though maintaining it may not be any easier than TeX syntax.  E.g.

```
//          │  ⌠T      {                                            }    │
//          │  |       {          ⌠a       dθ   ⌠θ                  }    │
// │ I  │ = │  |  ψ(t) { u(a,t) - |      ------ |   c(ξ) u (ξ,t) dξ } dt │
// │  2 │   │  |       {          ⌡γ(t)  k(θ,t) ⌡a        t         }    │
//          │  ⌡0      {                                            }    │
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit: I suppose I'm contending with this answer that you can write a much wider variety of formulae in a human readable fashion than might be initially obvious.

Comment: I suppose so. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have complex mathematical equations that require all sorts of symbols, you're better off writing them in your functional documentation, not in code documentation. i.e. a separate document.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX syntax is not overly complicated, and is much more human-readable (and human-writable!) than MathML (OK, this is an opinion). A bit of practice does help, but it's not anything you wouldn't pick up in a couple of hours. In my experience, writing a math-rich text in LaTeX is by far the most convenient option.

Depending on how complicated your formulas are -- or, rather, on whether you require fancy symbols -- I'd say you can either embed formulas into the code and use doxygen, or, as has already been noted, create a separate document.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I really like Managu's ASCII proposal and will adopt it.